# How to add fade effect to a JS id

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, fadeout

I have an image and a button, whenever I press the button the image disappears.  So I'd like to make it by a fade effect. Something like this:

```
#hide{-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5wBuV/4/

Comment: why not using jquery fadeOut ?

Comment: @FaceOfJock Well I am not good at JS. Thats why I tried to use CSS3. Do you know how to do it by JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery all you have to do is:

```
$("#hide").fadeOut("slow"); //or fast, or specific speed in milliseconds
//you can even throw a callback function if you need to
```

Or you can keep the javascript you had:

```
document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility = "hidden"; //or display = "none";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5wBuV/5/ updated your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use some JS:
$('#hide').fadeOut('slow');

If you want more advanced way, see more in [Jquery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

For animate effect, you can google "jquery easing"

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery `fadeOut()`:

```
 $("#clickedButton").click( function() {
     $('#hide').fadeOut('1000');

});
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/SV86Y/)**